# Java Enum to find the Values givng null

Tags: java, enums

I have following code: I want to get value `Approved` when I pass `A`, and if I passed `R` then I should get `Reject New` but its not working and giving me null value.

```
public enum MyEnum {
    A("Approved"),
    R("Reject New"),

    private String status;

    private MyEnum(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public static MyEnum fromString(String text) {
        return Arrays.stream(values())
          .filter(v -> v.status.equalsIgnoreCase(text))
          .findFirst()
          .orElse(null);
    }
}
```

Another Code:

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(MyEnum.fromString("A"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Then use `v.name().equalsIgnoreCase(text)` . Also note that `MyEnum.valueOf("A")` would also return the expected enum value, but is case-sensitive.

Comment: " I want to get value Approved when I pass A ..." - that doesn't fit `MyEnum fromString(String text)` because you return an instance of `MyEnum` which has the values A and R. "Approved" is a `String` property of those values so if you want your method to convert "A" to "Approved" the return value would have to be `String` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `valueOf()` directly.
This is **case-sensitive** and throws an error when it doesn't find the corresponding `enum`.

---

You need to look for the *name* field, not the *status* field:

```
public static MyEnum fromString(String text) {
        return Arrays.stream(values())
          .filter(v -> v.name().equalsIgnoreCase(text))
          .findFirst()
          .orElse(null);
    }
}
```

And once you have your enum, call the `getStatus()` method to return `Approved`:

```
    MyEnum foundEnum = MyEnum.fromString("A");
    System.out.println(foundEnum != null ? foundEnum.getStatus() : "- Not found -");
```

---

Or use the `Optional` approach:

```
public static Optional<MyEnum> fromStringOptional(String text) {
    try {
        return Optional.of(MyEnum.valueOf(text));
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException|NullPointerException e) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

And do

```
Optional<MyEnum> foundEnum3 = MyEnum.fromStringOptional(searchString);
System.out.println(foundEnum3.map(a -> a.getStatus()).orElse("- Not found -"));
System.out.println(foundEnum3.isPresent() ? foundEnum3.getStatus() : "- Not found -");
```

---

Full example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Optional;

public class EnumDemo {

    public enum MyEnum {
        A("Approved"),
        R("Reject New");

        private String status;

        private MyEnum(String status) {
            this.status = status;
        }

        public String getStatus() {
            return status;
        }

        public static MyEnum getEnumfromString(String text) {
            return Arrays.stream(values())
              .filter(v -> v.name().equalsIgnoreCase(text))
              .findFirst()
              .orElse(null);
        }

        public static String getStatusfromString(String text) {
            MyEnum found = Arrays.stream(values())
                  .filter(v -> v.name().equalsIgnoreCase(text))
                  .findFirst()
                  .orElse(null);
            return found != null ? found.getStatus() : "- Not found -";
        }

        public static Optional<MyEnum> getOptionalfromString(String text) {
            try {
                return Optional.of(MyEnum.valueOf(text));
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException|NullPointerException e) {
                return Optional.empty();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void doCalls(String searchString) {
        System.out.print("Call 1: ");
        MyEnum foundEnum = MyEnum.getEnumfromString(searchString);
        System.out.println(foundEnum != null ? foundEnum.getStatus() : "- Not found -");

        System.out.print("Call 2: ");
        System.out.println(MyEnum.getStatusfromString(searchString));

        System.out.println("Call 3 :");
        System.out.print(" A: ");
        Optional<MyEnum> foundOptional = MyEnum.getOptionalfromString(searchString);
        System.out.println(foundOptional.map(a -> a.getStatus()).orElse("- Not found -"));
        //or this, which only prints if the enum was found
        System.out.print(" B: ");
        foundOptional.ifPresent(a -> System.out.println(a.getStatus()));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Existing enum: 'A'");
        doCalls("A");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Non-existing enum: 'B'");
        doCalls("B");
    }
}
```

Test output:

> Existing enum: 'A'
>   Call 1: Approved
>   Call 2: Approved
>   Call 3 :
>    A: Approved
>    B: Approved
>
> Non-existing enum: 'B'
>   Call 1: - Not found -
>   Call 2: - Not found -
>   Call 3 :
>    A: - Not found -
>    B:

Answer (score 4):

You are comparing the wrong String. It should be

```
 System.out.println(MyEnum.fromString("Approved"));
```

---

To get the enum you can use the `valueOf`

```
System.out.println(MyEnum.valueOf("A").getStatus()); // prints Approved
```

Comment: I want to pass A and get the value Approved. I want other way around

Comment: @PAA See the second version

Comment: Do not use `valueOf()` like this. If you pass a non-existant value, the value in the wrong case or the value with an extra space, this will cause errors.

Comment: @GeorgeDerpi He is already expecting a `null` value from his `fromString` method. So I see no issues here since `null` is a valid return.

Comment: The first code implies that he is looking for the enum based on the status, but it is the reverse. The second code with valueOf(), will crash in all the cases I mentioned in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

Your `fromString()` method compares the enum values' `status` property to the passed parameter:

```
v.status.equalsIgnoreCase(text)
```

Thus when you pass `"A"` as `text` that will be compared to `"Approved"` and `"Reject New"` and neither of those will match.

If you want to get the enum for `"A"` which seems to be the value's name use `MyEnum.valueOf("A")`.

Comment: With ValueOf and v.name().equalsIgnoreCase(text), in both ways I dont get Approved values. Its not working

Comment: @PAA you might want to share your code the. Note that `"Approved"` is a property of the enum and not its name. If you want to get that string then use `MyEnum.valueOf("A").getStatus()` - of course you'd have to handle the null case as well.

Answer (score 0):

simple way to do it and also you can make it generic but not recommended

```
public static MyEnum fromString(String text) {
        try {
            return Enum.valueOf(MyEnum.class, text.toUpperCase());
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return null;
    }
```

calling  method

```
System.out.println(MyEnum.fromString("A"));
```

output :

```
A
```